# Recursion in R pseudo random numbers

Tags: r, recursion, random

I have to use recursion to produce pseudo random numbers. For fixed values a, b and c, I need to calculate:
x_n+1 = (a * x_n + c) modulo 2^b. Random numbers are obtained by the function R_n = x_n / (2^b). I need to save these R_n values to make a histogram. How can I make a function in R that uses it's previous values x_n to produce x_n+1? I have made a start with my code, it's listed below.

```
a=5
b=4
c=3
k=10000
random <- function(x) {
  if(x<k){
    x = (a*x+c)%%2^b
    k++
  }
}
```

Comment: What should `x_0` be? (That is, what should happen the first time?)

Comment: What happens if `x >= k`? Your function returns `NULL` (and is not valid R code anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a thought for starters,

```r
random <- function(a = 5, b = 4, c = 3, k = 10000, x0 = 1) {
  x <- x0 # or some other sane default
  function(n = 1) {
    newx <- Reduce(function(oldx, ign) (a*oldx + c) %% (2^b), seq_len(n),
                   init = x, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
    # if (x >= k)? do something else
    if (length(newx)) {
      x <<- newx[length(newx)]
      k <<- k + n
    }
    newx
  }
}
```

The premise is that the `random` function is a *setup* function that returns a function. This inner function has its `a`, `b`, `c`, `k`, and previous `x` variables stored within it.

```r
thisran <- random()
thisran()
# [1] 8
thisran(3)
# [1] 11 10  5
```

I haven't studied creating PRNG in depth, but I'm inferring that `x0` here is effectively your *seed*. I'm not certain why you had a `if (x<k)` conditional in your function; since `k` was never used otherwise, just incremented, I'm thinking it only serves as a termination indicator for your PRNG (so it is not infinite).

If need be, the current `k` value (and other variables, for that matter) can be peeked-at with

```r
get("k", environment(thisran))
# [1] 10003
```

---

BTW: the use of `Reduce` might seem like an unnecessary complication, but it enables the `ran(n)` functionality, similar to other PRNGs in R. That is, one can do `runif(7)` for seven random numbers, and I thought it would be useful to do that here. The use of `Reduce` is required in that case since each calculation depends on the results from the previous calculation, so a sample `replicate` or `sapply` would not work (without some contrived coding that I wanted to avoid).